# Include a custom carousel to show it only on the home page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom carousel that I want to show only the home page.  I've placed the carousel's code a file called **slider.php** I can get the slider to show  when I include it inside the **header.php** file:

```
<?php require('../BlueQuote/wp-content/themes/greatmag/slider.php'); ?>
```

But when I place it in **index.php** or in **home.php** it's not showing up on the page (for curiosity I've tried including it inside **footer.php** and it does show up there as well, but that's not what I need). I'm using a child theme, based on the [GreatMag](https://wordpress.org/themes/greatmag/) theme. *WordPress 4.9.4* and *PHP 7* with *XAMPP* on *Windows 7*, thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: In the options, have you configued the home page to use a specific page?

Comment: Yes I have set it up, on localhost it's http://localhost/BlueQuote/

Comment: That's not what I mean. The homepage of a WordPress blog can be set to use the blogroll, or a specific page template. If you're using the latter, the template might not be `home.php` or `index.php`.

Comment: Oh I get it, yes I've set it up under Settings > Reading> 
Your homepage displays: A static page (select below) Homepage: home and post page is the news page.

Comment: Okay, so whichever template the page called Home is using, is where you need to add your carousel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to debug this theme and found the following.

Header.php will force this to show on every page that uses a header (so this won't work), and index.php is a generic template file and is used to display a page when nothing more specific matches a query (so this won't work too).

So you have to edit only *home.php* file. Add this code after the php function and right before the content area div. This is a snippet of the part:

```
/.../

} else {
    $cols = 'col-md-8';
}
?>

<!-- This is where your code starts -->
<?php require('../BlueQuote/wp-content/themes/greatmag/slider.php'); ?>
<!--- This is where your code ends -->

    <div id="primary" class="content-area <?php echo $cols; ?>">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

        <?php
        if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <div class="<?php greatmag_blog_layout(); ?>">
                <?php greatmag_grid_sizer(); ?>
/.../
```

This should do the trick, because you were trying to add code to a wrong part.